# Use Same Product ID's for Both Mac and iOS In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, mac-app-store

I have a iOS application with In-App Purchase for some non-consumable products. Now we are planning to build a application on Mac OS X with all the features of iOS and have Mac In-App Purchase. Now when I try to add the iOS product ID's in my Mac *iTunes Connect* account, it wont allow me to do that. It says I can't use same product ID which is already in use.

I think its common for iOS and Mac apps to use same product ID's for delivering same product.

**Now my question:** *Is it possible to have same product ID's created on both iOS and Mac iTunes connect ? Am I missing something here?*

Thanks,

-Anish

Answer (score 5):

To answer my own question, as of now its not possible for both Mac and iOS in-App purchase to have same product id's. I got this info from Apple engineers at WWDC2012. Apple suggests we use iCloud internally to track purchases between iOS and Mac OS if you want your users not to pay for using same product on either of the devices.

-Anish